# getting error while installing laravel in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have PHP version:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.9-1
```

composer version:

```
Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25
```

Now 
I am getting this error and I could not be able to solve this because I am new to this technology.

```
 composer global require "laravel/installer"
    Changed current directory to /home/indous-ubuntu/.composer
    Using version ^1.4 for laravel/installer
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
        - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
        - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].

      To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini

      You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

If anyone knows what's the issue, please help me with this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like you either haven't installed the PHP zip etension or haven't enabled it.

Comment: read this article https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/352

Comment: Try either `sudo apt-get install php-zip` or `sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip` Then, you might have to restart your web server: `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo service nginx restart` Hope this helps you! Let me know what issue occurs!

Comment: You can also install `php7.0-zip ` if you want!

Comment: i did this not working.

Comment: Do you restart the `apache` after install?

Comment: Any errors you get now?

Comment: @HirenGohel  sudo service apache2 restart
[sudo] password for indous-ubuntu: 
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Do this 2 command please: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and
`sudo systemctl restart apache2.service` Let me know what happened?

Comment: Fixed your problem??

Comment: not yet have to work on some other things

Comment: Ok, np. If you need some help from me, comment it here! I will post my answer! :)

Comment: sure thank you :))

Comment: @P_M Have you fixed this? Have you got any errors now?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the composer.json file and replace with this

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "laracasts/commander": "~1.0",
    "laracasts/validation": "~1.0",
    "laracasts/presenter": "0.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0"
},
```

reference of this code and more details [Reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/error-trying-to-require-dependencies)

Comment: i did changes in compoer.json file as you said and after that i hit the composer update command. BUT it gives me erro like this.  ===> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Answer (score 0):

Enable your php ext-zip lib. install it with

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` for php version 7

Answer (score 0):

As it has been clearly described in the error, you are missing php-zip extension:

> Problem 1
>           - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

Try installing it using this command (use `sudo`):

```
apt-get install php-zip
```

It will install it for PHP7 automatically as its the default version for PHP in Ubuntu repositories.

*P.S: If you have php-zip already installed and it still does not work, add the extension to your `php.ini` files in: `/etc/php` and you are good to go.*